# Python: for loop including lines outside of loop

Tags: python, for-loop, iteration

I'm using a for loop to create a multi-line string.  After the loop is done I want to call a popup window and display the string.  For some reason it calls the popup window with each iteration, even though the call is after the for loop, and indented correctly.  I can't find anything like this online.  Any ideas?

```
string = ""
for color in highlight_report_dict:
    if highlight_report_dict[color] == []:
        continue
    else:
        string += '{}\n'.format(color)
        for item in highlight_report_dict[color]:
            start = str(int(float(item[0])))+'.0'  #changes '3.34' to '3.0', etc for any index
            end = str(int(float(item[1])))+'.0'
            start = index_key[start]
            end = index_key[end]
            string += '{} - {}\n'.format(start, end)
print string #Why does it call popup() during for loop???
popup(string)
```

The output I'm expecting is something like:

"Blue
1.4-2.5

Yellow
2.6-3.1"

But what I'm getting is:

"Blue 
1.4-2.5

Blue 
1.4-2.5

Yellow 
2.6-3.1"

If needed, here is the entire function:

```
def highlight_report():
    tag_list = t.tag_names()[1:] #creates list of all highlight tag colors, removing 'ins' tag
    start = '1.0'
    end = t.index(END)

    highlight_report_dict = {}

    for color in tag_list:
        highlight_report_dict[color] = []
        cycle = True
        while cycle:
            highlight_report_dict[color].append(t.tag_nextrange(color, start, end))

            try:
                start = highlight_report_dict[color][-1][1]  #uses previous tag end as new start
            except IndexError:
                start = '1.0'
                cycle = False
                if highlight_report_dict[color][-1] == ():  #removes empty tuple created at end of cycle
                    del highlight_report_dict[color][-1]


    string = ""
    for color in highlight_report_dict:
        if highlight_report_dict[color] == []:
            continue
        else:
            string += '{}\n'.format(color)
            for item in highlight_report_dict[color]:
                start = str(int(float(item[0])))+'.0'  #changes '3.34' to '3.0', etc for any index
                end = str(int(float(item[1])))+'.0'
                start = index_key[start]
                end = index_key[end]
                string += '{} - {}\n'.format(start, end)
    print string #Why does it call popup() during for loop???
    popup(string)
```

Comment: This is extremely unusual. Try inserting a newline between the last line of the for-loop and ''print string''. Double-check all your indenting, as well. The interpreter is sometimes ornery.

Comment: Have you tried to run this without `popup(string)`?

Comment: Can you edit your question to show the indents? You might be calling it within a for loop or something.

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. Your code actually raises an exception and seems to be unnecessarily long.

Comment: @manglano: I've tried inserting a newline as you suggest, but it doesn't change the outcome.

Comment: @lafexlos: I've tried removing the popup(string) call, but it doesn't affect the outcome, and ultimately I need to call the popup window with that text, so I'd want to leave that there.  I just added the print statement for testing.

Comment: @jape : I apologize if my I didn't post my code correctly.  When I view it on stackoverflow all the indents are retained and showing... should I be doing something different to post this question?

Comment: @goyo: This is just one function inside a much larger program... I'm not sure how to post a complete (and especially minimal) example without posting the whole program... I'm definitely open to suggestions though.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.  This was a tab vs. four spaces issue.  I'd copied text from one editor to Sublime Text.  Some of the text was tabbed, some was four spaces.  I had Sublime convert all tabs into four spaces, and now my for loop works as expected.